# iText PDF not working in Firefox

Tags: itext

My iText pdf document works fine in IE but does not work in Firefox. I get this jumbled text.

����I{:�3�М֠� n:^;q0�����v�x����ɕ����y��~�E�?9|��f����$�c"h��Z�f�YR7L[��w9|�� ��H��V0�������x>B_�Z|��SK�����dB��������n�r�S���+;���ɘ����aJ��Ǹ~r��f�g�q�☄��f[�7���HТ�ڲ��*W�=`l��:�����Լ���l��)�8 C��ﳵ��/N79���Ԛg��%�P���(uE�.e�����{,r�3�e�Xw^����D���0rwi�<��Y�x5 � ��ި |⿊�㹳w�܋���L�.6�����Z�=*��9ӆ endstream endobj 126 0 obj <>/ProcSet [/PDF /Text

Below is my jsp code. I saw another thread with the similiar problem BUT there was no SOLUTION. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have Adobe Reader XI installed. Please let me know if you need any other info.

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, widthMargin, widthMargin, heightMargin, heightMargin);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();

    document.add(createImageTable(image1,image2));

    document.close();

         //response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
         response.setContentType("application/pdf");        
         response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
             "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
         response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
         // setting the content type
         response.setContentType("application/pdf");
         String countryName = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filename.indexOf("."));
         //String attachment = "attachment; filename=" + countryName + ".pdf";
         String attachment = "inline; filename=" + countryName + ".pdf";
         response.setHeader("Content-disposition",attachment);


         response.setContentLength(baos.size());
         // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
         OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
         baos.writeTo(os);
         os.flush();
         os.close();
```

Comment: Looks like a Unicode encoding error.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Any idea?

Comment: Questions like this are impossible to answer remotely. Why? Because there may not be an error in your JSP. Proof: in MSIE, the PDF is shown correctly. Chances are the PDF is also shown correctly on Firefox on other machines. Everything points into the direction of a local configuration problem. Local configuration problems are hard to solve by third parties because they can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Native reading of pdfs in Firefox is not yet implemented (tested on Firefox 22.0).

You need to add a module :
[Disable Built-in pdf viewer and use another viewer](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer)